# Cannot play DRM protected video streams on Webview2

Tags: c#, video-streaming, webview2

I created WinUI 3.0 project that used Webview2 v1.0.818.41 and loaded my video streaming app into it, but the video will not play and reports multiple DRM errors.

I also checked if video streaming works for the app in the version of Chromium Edge I have installed on my computer, and it does. Here is my user agent string, which I verified matches the user agent string I get from Webview2:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36 Ege/90.0.818.62`

After a bit of investigation, I figured out that `navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess` is defined on Chromium Edge but is not defined on the client in Webview2. Because this is a UWP app, I suspect one of four possibilities as to why DRM fails:

1. Developer mode?

   - I know previously that Legacy Edge running on an Xbox One in developer mode restricts playback of DRM content to SL-150 and below. Could this be true of Webview2, but even more restrictive than Legacy Edge?
2. Missing app permission or some other setting?

   - I have set the content URI's in the manifest appropriately, and nothing appears out of sorts with the app permissions.
3. Webview2 does not have EME support yet?

   - If true, this is surprising since EME is a W3C specification, and support is already built into Chromium Edge.
4. Webview2 needs instantiation with some unspecified options/flags?

Of relevant importance, I should also note that I have seen other video streaming apps using Webview2. The only way I can tell is when an error occurs, but I have seen error messages on those apps that indicate the new component is in use, so I know DRM has somehow been figured out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to identify that the root cause of this issue was a 3rd party tool not properly handling streams. However, I did discover the following along the way:

1. Webview2 does support EME as of v1.0.818.41
2. Developer mode does not affect the ability to play DRM protected content
3. URLs must use HTTPS, not HTTP or else `navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess` is undefined.
4. No special app permissions or flags on Webview2 are required